# How to share Android USB tethered network on the entire LAN?

Tags: networking, server, internet, android, tethering

I have a headless Ubuntu 17.04 installed on my local server. I want to use it as the default gateway on the network (this is the easier part).

I have an Android phone running the latest 8.1 release. When I connect it to the Ubuntu server and I turn on USB tethering on my phone I want all outgoing network traffic to go through the phone not the default gateway (which is the router/cable modem currently).

How can I achieve this? I believe the network provided by the Android system is randomly selected when I turn on tethering (192.168.X.0/24). My internal network is on 192.168.0.0/16.

Comment: You will need to specify your gateway your android phone. In /etc/network/interfaces you can define the gateway for your network. Be sure it has the same subnet as your android phone 192.168.x.0/24. Avoid the random selection of the subnet defined on your phone. You would better define your own local subnet on your phone. If the DHCP server is not on your phone, then you need to define a static ip address for your phone/gateway and tell the DHCP server where the gateway is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify your gateway your android phone. In /etc/network/interfaces on your server you can define the gateway for your network. Define default gateway your android phone for your server. Be sure your usb interface is shown up in ifconfig. When yes then define for your eth0 interface the gateway ip the ip address of your android phone.